# Get Attribute Customer in Magento2 with GraphQL

Tags: graphql, magento2

I created new attributes for customer but I want to insert them into a structure in graphql.
Where there is an array called Garage with the new attributes.
It is already being displayed normally in the structure when I use static data but now I need to make it dynamic through the database according to the customer id.
Seeing a model of the customer himself I saw that a command is executed to bring but I would like to bring item by item and put it in the array.

CustomerGarage.php

```
    <?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Enterprise\GraphQL\Model\Resolver;

use Magento\CustomerGraphQl\Model\Customer\GetCustomer;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlAuthorizationException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo;
use Magento\CustomerGraphQl\Model\Customer\ExtractCustomerData;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\GraphQl\Model\Query\ContextInterface;

/**
 * Customers field resolver, used for GraphQL request processing.
 */
class CustomerGarage implements ResolverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var GetCustomer
     */
    private $getCustomer;

    /**
     * @var ExtractCustomerData
     */
    private $extractCustomerData;

    /**
     * @param GetCustomer $getCustomer
     * @param ExtractCustomerData $extractCustomerData
     */
    public function __construct(
        GetCustomer $getCustomer,
        ExtractCustomerData $extractCustomerData
    ) {
        $this->getCustomer = $getCustomer;
        $this->extractCustomerData = $extractCustomerData;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function resolve(
        Field $field,
        $context,
        ResolveInfo $info,
        array $value = null,
        array $args = null
    ) {
        /** @var ContextInterface $context */
        if (false === $context->getExtensionAttributes()->getIsCustomer()) {
            throw new GraphQlAuthorizationException(__('The current customer isn\'t authorized.'));
        }

        $customer = $this->getCustomer->execute($context);
        
        $model[] = array(
            "make" => "Teste",
            "model" => $this->extractCustomerData->execute($customer),
            "specification" => "1.0",
            "year" => 2020,
            "isDefault" => "Teste"
        );
        
        return $model;
    }
}
```

Schema.graphql

```
type Customer {
    garage: [CustomerGarage] @doc(description: "An array containing the customer's shipping and billing addresses") @resolver(class: "Enterprise\\GraphQL\\Model\\Resolver\\CustomerGarage")
}

type CustomerGarage {
    make: String @doc(description: "The customer's ZIP or postal code")
    model: String @doc(description: "The customer's ZIP or postal code")
    specification: String @doc(description: "The customer's ZIP or postal code")
    year: Int
    isDefault: String @doc(description: "The customer's ZIP or postal code")
}
type Cart {
    vehicle: String
    isPickup: Boolean
    scheduledDate: String
}
```

requireGraphQL

```
{
  customer {
    firstname
    lastname
    garage{
      make
      model
    }
  }
```

ResponseGraphQL

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Internal server error",
      "extensions": {
        "category": "internal"
      },
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 5,
          "column": 5
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "customer",
        "garage"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "customer": {
      "firstname": "Carlo",
      "lastname": "Sanchez",
      "garage": null
    }
  }
}
    }
```

Comment: you "model" graphql attribute definition specifies that it has a String value, but Magento\CustomerGraphQl\Model\Customer\ExtractCustomerData::execute returns an array, you add the value (array) directly as the model value it seems, this seems a bit off

Answer (score 0):

the resolver parameter `$value` should already contain all of the customer's data loaded in an array, you can check if you have the data you need there. And if you need the customer data model instance, you can get it from `$value['model']`.

This is because the value of the parameter `$value` is whatever the parent resolver returns, in this case, it is `\Magento\CustomerGraphQl\Model\Resolver\Customer::resolve` defined here `vendor/magento/module-customer-graph-ql/etc/schema.graphqls`